# Using \in with uppercase letters does not look good

Tags: math-mode

I have the following Latexcode:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{G} = A_{polygon} - \sum \limits_{C \in \Xi} A(C)
\end{equation}
```

However, the sum index looks bad in my eyes, as the "is element of" sign is a little lower than the other two letters. It looks badly aligned. 
Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to change to to smaller case letters as I have a convention for letter cases in my document.

edit:
I've added a picture

[image: Picture of the rendered latexcode.]

I'd like the element sign to be above the red line i.e. vertically centered with C and Ξ.

Comment: That is basically just how it looks in the standard font. It looks differently in other fonts. BTW: please remember to post full minimal examples instead of sniplets. Not everyone knows where `\mathscr` comes from

Comment: I should be `\mathscr{G} = A_{\mathrm{polygon}} - \sum_{C \in \Xi} A(C)`, but, in any case, I don't think it looks bad.

Comment: @JnxF. no please don't promote this, `\text` is for textual comments, `polygon` is not a comment but an index. Plus if the textual context is italic then so is the outout from `\text` which is not what you want here.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've added an image to make it more cleared what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the "does not look good" is in my opinion quite a matter of taste, you can easily define a new version by putting the `\in` in a box and raising the box by its depth:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myin}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@myin\relax}}
\def\@myin#1#2{{\setbox0=\hbox{\m@th$#1\in$}\raise\dp0\box0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}                      

Original: $A\in B$, $\displaystyle\sum_{A\in B}$
New: $A\myin B$, $\displaystyle\sum_{A\myin B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, looks are always a matter of taste. Thank you for fulfilling my expectations :-) I'd upvote but I'm still collecting the required rep.