# General misplacement of the element sign

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I recently noticed that the element sign in latex is misplaced, not only in combination with `\mathbb{R}` as you can see in my example but also with any other sign. It doesn't matter in which math mode do you use it. I asked a friend of mine and he made the same observation so it seems this does not depend on PDF viewer, compiler, operating system et cetera.

I spent some time in searching online but did not find any information about that behavior which was, indeed quite bewildering, since people are very nit-picking when it comes to the usage of `\coloneqq` instead of `:=` but they don't mind that obvious misplacement of the highly used element sign.

If there is any existing workaround I would be glad to know about. I ask for apology if there is an existing question which I did not find.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, mathtools}

\begin{document}
$1+1+1+1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\underbrace{1+1+1+1}_{\in \mathbb{R}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don’t post a MWE as a screenshot. We can’t easily compile it. You should copy and paste it as a code block. Thanks!

Comment: @Davislor You can easily reproduce this problem by typing something like $1 \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\underbrace{1+1+1+1}_{\in \mathbb{R}}$ to see the misplacement. The screenshot is just to illustrate my explanations. This explicitely is not a MWE. But as requested, I added one in my post.

Comment: This depends entirely on what packages you load.

Comment: @Davislor There is a proper MWE now.

Comment: The element sign and its reverse are binary operators, and as such they are centered vertically on the math axis.  That means their vertical center will be on a line with the horizontal bar of a plus sign and the midpoint of an equals sign.  In a smaller size than found in Computer Modern, they may appear to be sitting on the baseline, but that is an optical illusion; if that is the actual placement, it is incorrect.

Comment: You can shift the baseline of the glyph using a virtual font.

Comment: Related: [Using `\in` with uppercase letters does not look good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326285/82917).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the usual shape of `\in`. Some fonts have a smaller one, but you will always see that the straight middle bar sits at the same height as fraction lines.

You could change the symbol by slightly scaling it if it extends below the baseline. (I'd not do it, to be honest.)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <--- This is important for German
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}

\makeatletter
\let\standard@in\in
\DeclareRobustCommand{\in}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\scaled@in\relax}}
\newcommand{\scaled@in}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\standard@in$}%
  \ifdim\dp\z@>\z@
    \raisebox{\depth}{\resizebox{!}{\dimexpr\ht\z@-\dp\z@}{\copy\z@}}%
  \else
    \box\z@
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$1+1+1+1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\underbrace{1+1+1+1}_{\in \mathbb{R}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I leave as an exercise changing also `\notin`.

Note that loading `inputenc` with `utf8` is not necessary nowadays. Instead, loading `fontenc` with the `T1` option is really needed for German.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Also with T1!

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to the metrics of the ∈ glyph in your math font.  That’s just how it’s traditionally been drawn.  But here’s a template that raises it (by half the difference between the height of the glyphs 0 and ∈).  Try it out with different math fonts.

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{settobox}

\newlength\inheight
\newlength\textstyleraisein
\newlength\displaystyleraisein
\newlength\scriptstyleraisein
\newlength\sscriptstyleraisein

\newsavebox\inbox
\newsavebox\zerobox

\savebox{\inbox}{\( \textstyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \textstyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\textstyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\textstyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\textstyleraisein}{0.5\textstyleraisein}
\savebox{\inbox}{\( \displaystyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \displaystyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\displaystyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\displaystyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\displaystyleraisein}{0.5\displaystyleraisein}
\savebox{\inbox}{\( \scriptstyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \scriptstyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\scriptstyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\scriptstyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\scriptstyleraisein}{0.5\scriptstyleraisein}
\savebox{\inbox}{\( \scriptscriptstyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \scriptscriptstyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\sscriptstyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\sscriptstyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\sscriptstyleraisein}{0.5\sscriptstyleraisein}
\newcommand\isin{\mathrel{\mathchoice%
{\raisebox{\displaystyleraisein}{\(\displaystyle\in\)}}%
{\raisebox{\textstyleraisein}{\(\textstyle\in\)}}%
{\raisebox{\scriptstyleraisein}{\(\scriptstyle\in\)}}%
{\raisebox{\sscriptstyleraisein}{\(\scriptscriptstyle\in\)}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\( 0 \isin \mathbb{R}_{\isin \mathbb{R}_{\isin \mathbb{R}}} \)
\[
\underbrace{{\lambda a^i - c_i}}_{\isin \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}^+_0} 
\underbrace{x_i}_{\isin \mathbb{R}} = 0 \isin \mathbb{R}
\]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Newpxmath font sample]

With `fourier` instead of `newpxmath`:

[image: Fourier font sample]

With the Charter option of `mathdesign`:

[image: Charter/Math Design sample]

As requested, here is an example that places it side-by-side with a plus sign.  As you can see, the default (on the left) aligns `\in` with `+` in most fonts, including `stix`.  On the right, I show what it looks like raised.

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, stix}
\usepackage{settobox}

%% Formatting for a MWE on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newlength\inheight
\newlength\textstyleraisein
\newlength\displaystyleraisein
\newlength\scriptstyleraisein
\newlength\sscriptstyleraisein

\newsavebox\inbox
\newsavebox\zerobox

\savebox{\inbox}{\( \textstyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \textstyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\textstyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\textstyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\textstyleraisein}{0.5\textstyleraisein}
\savebox{\inbox}{\( \displaystyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \displaystyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\displaystyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\displaystyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\displaystyleraisein}{0.5\displaystyleraisein}
\savebox{\inbox}{\( \scriptstyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \scriptstyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\scriptstyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\scriptstyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\scriptstyleraisein}{0.5\scriptstyleraisein}
\savebox{\inbox}{\( \scriptscriptstyle\in \)}
\savebox{\zerobox}{\( \scriptscriptstyle 0 \)}
\settoboxheight{\inheight}{\inbox}
\settoboxheight{\sscriptstyleraisein}{\zerobox}
\addtolength{\sscriptstyleraisein}{-\inheight}
\setlength{\sscriptstyleraisein}{0.5\sscriptstyleraisein}
\newcommand\isin{\mathrel{\mathchoice%
{\raisebox{\displaystyleraisein}{\(\displaystyle\in\)}}%
{\raisebox{\textstyleraisein}{\(\textstyle\in\)}}%
{\raisebox{\scriptstyleraisein}{\(\scriptstyle\in\)}}%
{\raisebox{\sscriptstyleraisein}{\(\scriptscriptstyle\in\)}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\[ 1+1+1+1 \in \mathbb{R} \qquad 1+1+1+1 \isin \mathbb{R} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX font sample]

Comment: Please, don’t use the `minimal` class for examples. It’s not meant for this purpose.

Comment: @egreg I take it for granted that you know what you’re talking about. Unfortunately, I don’t.

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}` is your friend.

Comment: @egreg It is, and I can use another class instead that supports geometry, sections, etc.

Comment: An example with a plus sign in the same string of math as the element sign would be instructive.  (The example in the question would do nicely.)

Comment: @barbara beeton This was the example in the question before I added an explicite MWE.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Okay, I added an example with plus signs.

Comment: @Davislor -- Thanks.  I'm afraid this now makes me wonder whether the plus signs are misaligned.  (I know they're not.)

Comment: I could simplify this a lot by using `\mathpalette`.